# MySQL: Show "Added ... ago" (TIMESTAMPS)

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm trying to add something like "Added 1 hour, 24 minutes ago" or "Added 1 month ago" etc to my website.
I tried with the solution here but it didn't work: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10362190

My timestamp is in this format; YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS . (Using `NOW();`)

Sorry if I'm not descriptive enough - I tried searching on google, and to tell the truth, there wasn't any solid working solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know how to Google... http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/making-our-own-twitter-timeline/
And what you have is not a UNIX timestamp, you will need to convert it by using `strtotime()`

```
function relativeTime($dt,$precision=2)
{
    $times=array(   365*24*60*60    => "year",
                30*24*60*60     => "month",
                7*24*60*60      => "week",
                24*60*60        => "day",
                60*60           => "hour",
                60              => "minute",
                1               => "second");

    $passed=time()-$dt;

    if($passed<5)
    {
        $output='less than 5 seconds ago';
    }
    else
    {
        $output=array();
        $exit=0;
        foreach($times as $period=>$name)
        {
            if($exit>=$precision || ($exit>0 && $period<60))    break;
            $result = floor($passed/$period);

            if($result>0)
            {
                $output[]=$result.' '.$name.($result==1?'':'s');
                $passed-=$result*$period;
                $exit++;
            }

            else if($exit>0) $exit++;

        }
        $output=implode(' and ',$output).' ago';
    }

    return $output;
}
```